# запрос POST с сервера Node.js для PHP

Tags: node.js, axios

Товарищи, скажите что делаю не так?

Делаю запрос post node.js, но ответ не приходит
Пробовал библиотеки axios, request, request-promise, http(нативный) ...
Аналогичный запрос на PHP выдает прекрасный результат.

В чем подвох?

пример который не работает javascript:

```
var key = querystring.stringify({ 'api_key': 'your_key'});
axios({
  method:'POST',
  url: 'https://miratext.ru/api2/call/user/balance',
  responseType : 'json' ,
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise',
    'Content-Length': key.length ,
  },
  content: key,
})
.then(function(response) {
   console.log('RESPONSE', response.data);
   console.log('RESPONSE', response.status);
   console.log('RESPONSE', response.statusText);
   console.log('RESPONSE', response.headers);
   console.log('RESPONSE', response.config);
}).catch(function (error) {
   if (error.response) {
     console.log('ERROR1 ', error.response.data);
     console.log('ERROR2 ', error.response.status);
     console.log('ERROR3 ', error.response.headers);
   } else if (error.request) {
     console.log('ERROR4 ', error.request);
   } else {
     console.log('ERROR5 ', error.message);
   }
     console.log('ERROR6 ', error.config);
});
```

пример рабочий php:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://miratext.ru/api2/call/user/balance');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('api_key' => 'your_key')));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(json_decode($result, true));
```

Comment: для axios нужно было написать `data: { api_key: 'your_key' }` вместо `content: key`

Answer (score 1):

Видимо где-то допустил опечатку

Решение:

```
var url = 'https://miratext.ru/api2/call/user/balance';
var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: url,
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise',
        'Content-Length': key.length,
      },
      'content': key,
      'body': key,
      json: true
    };
    rp(options, function (err, res) {
       console.log('REQUEST RESULTS:', err, res.statusCode);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
       console.log('Ответ ', result);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
       console.log(err);
  });
```